# Can't find elements but they exist Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have encountered a problem: the program does not see the elements and cannot print them. Though, I use it several times in code and it worked the first time. A little later, as I said, it stops seeing the element:

HTML code:

```
<div class="entries-container">
 <div class="row step finished">...</div>
 <div class="row step finished">...</div>
</div>
```

Python code:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='entries-container']/div")
print(len(elements))
print(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='entries-container']/div"))
```

Console output:

```
0
[]
```

If instead of elements to find 1 element (`print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='entries-container']/div"))`), then an error will appear in the console, Unable to locale element

What is the problem? Is there another way to find an element?

**Updated:** I just recreated the HTML page and the program started working. Most likely it was a bug.

Comment: Does `elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "entries-container")` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get string value from the text nodes you have to invoke `.text` method. The following xpath expression selects all the div elements

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='entries-container']/div")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

See the provement from [here](http://xpather.com/23B09IAN)

Comment: I just recreated the HTML page and the program started working. Most likely it was a bug. Thanks for the answer, I hope our dialogue will help someone